# JDBI: querying a string column with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jdbi

I have a column `title` in a SQL table `myTable`.

Using Kotlin and JDBI, how would I go about getting all the distinct entries in this table?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
val jdbi = Jdbi.create("...url", "...user", "...password")

fun getTitles(): List<String> = jdbi.withHandleUnchecked { handle -> 
   handle.createQuery("select distinct(title) from myTable;")
         .mapTo(String.javaClass)
         .list()
```

However, this gives me the following exception:
`A bean, Companion was mapped which was not instantiable (cannot find appropriate constructor)`

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `String.javaClass` is not what I want here (as it is a different type than is required). It is `String::class.java`.